# How does one prove asymptotic normality of the Non-linear least squares from First order conditions?

Tags: econometrics, nonlinear-regression

Our model is $Y=X(\beta_0)+u$, where $u\sim IID(0,\sigma_0^2I)$, and $X(\beta)$ is a non-linear function of the beta.

When trying to minimize the $SSR(\beta)$ we get the following FOC:

$\nabla X(\beta)^T(Y-X(\beta))=0$, where $\nabla X(\beta)$ is the gradient.

How does one prove the asymptotic normality of $\hat\beta$ from this FOC?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

If we apply a taylor expansion of the first order to each component $X_t(\beta)$ of $X(\beta)$, we obtain $X_t(\beta)=X_t(\beta_0)+\nabla X(\bar\beta_{(t)})^T(\beta-\beta_0)$, where $\bar\beta_{(t)}$ is a point in the line segment that joins $\beta$ and $\beta_0$. This point may be different for each taylor expansion we do, and that's why it's indexed by $t$.

Inserting the taylor expansion in the FOC:
$n^{(-1/2)}(\nabla X(\beta)^T(u-\nabla \bar X^T(\beta-\beta_0))=0$, where $\nabla \bar X$ is the matrix with $\nabla X(\bar\beta_{(i)})$ as each i-th column.

Are all of the above calculations correct? I ask this because in this [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Econometric-Theory-Methods-International-Edition/dp/0195391055?ie=UTF8&ref_=asap_bc), the authors state in page 225 that we should obtain a term with second derivatives of $X(\beta)$... I do not understand why this is.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use a Taylor expansion and the mean value theorem. You can look for proofs for M estimation.

Comment: (1) Presumably you are asking to demonstrate asymptotic normality of the *solution* to the FOC ("first order conditions"), not asymptotic normality of $\beta$ itself.  (2) What is the relationship between $\beta_0$ and $\beta$? (3) Exactly what are the asymptotics you have in mind?  What happens to the $X$ values as the number of observations increases?  This can be important in cases where your FOC have multiple solutions (which is a hint @hejseb that an analysis of a Taylor expansion will succeed only if you make some additional assumptions).

Comment: @hejseb you're right, I've edited the question.

Comment: @whuber (1) you're right. (2) $\beta_0$ is beta's true value. I hadn't thought about the possibility of the FOC having more than 1 solution... But the book assumes asymptotic identifiability of $\beta_0$, which means $\hat\beta$ is consistent. So, I would think that it doesn't matter which solution we use, not sure though... How would the asymptotic behaviour usually be proved?

Comment: If it's identified there is only one solution. This assumption is made by eg Greene in his book. You will get a matrix of second derivatives when you do the expansion (expand the FOC, which already contains the first order derivatives. So the derivative of the first order gives you the second order.)

Comment: @hejseb But the Taylor expansion is linear in $\beta$, and the doing the derivative of the Taylor expansion w.r.t. $\beta$ just gives the gradient... 

$\nabla_{\hat\beta}X(\hat \beta)=\nabla_{\hat \beta}(X(\beta_0))+\nabla_{\hat\beta}(\nabla \bar X^T (\hat \beta-\beta_0)))=0+\nabla \bar X$

Comment: Maybe I can write up an answer tomorrow (I'm on the phone atm). In the meantime check slide 3 here: http://web.stanford.edu/~doubleh/eco273/newslides3.pdf

Comment: @hejseb I would really appreciate. I think I understand, but the slide is only for real-valued functions. It would change a bit the notation, since we're in the multivariate case, and the taylor expansion is just for scalar functions right?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea Taylor expansion works for vector valued functions too.

Comment: @mpiktas the function receives a vector, but must give a scalar.  We can only apply to these kind of functions, I think.

Comment: Taylor expansion holds for vector valued vector argument functions too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first order condition is
$$
g(b):=\frac{\partial S(\beta)}{\partial \beta}\bigg|_{\beta=b}=0
$$
by construction, as we define $b$ as the solution (we may here assume unique minimum, nice parameter space). Let $\beta_0$ be the true value and $\bar\beta$ a vector with elements satisfying $\bar{\beta}_i\in [\min\{b_i, \beta_{0, i}\}, \max\{b_i, \beta_{0, i}\}]$. Then
$$
g(b)=g(\beta_0)+\frac{\partial g(\beta)}{\partial \beta'}\bigg|_{\beta=\bar\beta}(b-\beta_0)=0.
$$
Note here that
$$
\frac{\partial g(\beta)}{\partial \beta}\bigg|_{\beta=\bar\beta}=\frac{\partial^2 S(\beta)}{\partial \beta\partial\beta'}\bigg|_{\beta=\bar\beta}
$$
a $p\times p$ matrix (where $p$ is the length of $\beta$). Rearrange the terms
\begin{align}
g(\beta_0)+\frac{\partial g(\beta)}{\partial \beta'}\bigg|_{\beta=\bar\beta}(b-\beta_0)&=0\\
\left(\frac{\partial g(\beta)}{\partial \beta'}\bigg|_{\beta=\bar\beta}\right)^{-1}g(\beta_0)+(b-\beta_0)&=0\\
\sqrt n(b-\beta_0)&=-\left(n^{-1}\frac{\partial g(\beta)}{\partial \beta'}\bigg|_{\beta=\bar\beta}\right)^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}g(\beta_0)
\end{align}

Usually, it is assumed that
\begin{align}
n^{-1}\frac{\partial g(\beta)}{\partial \beta'}\bigg|_{\beta=\beta_0}&\overset{p}\to Q \, (\text{pos. def.})\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}g(\beta_0) & \overset{d}{\to} N(0, \sigma^2Q).
\end{align}
Since $\bar{\beta}$ is sandwiched between $b$ and $\beta_0$ and $b\overset{p}{\to}\beta_0$, we may replace the evaluation at $\bar\beta$ by $\beta_0$ in the asymptotic analysis. By the continuous mapping theorem the inverse of the matrix of second derivatives will tend to $Q^{-1}$ and by Slutsky's theorem the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n}(b-\beta_0)$ is the same as that of
\begin{align}
-\left(n^{-1}\frac{\partial g(\beta)}{\partial \beta'}\bigg|_{\beta=\beta_0}\right)^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}g(\beta_0) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, \sigma^2Q^{-1}QQ^{-1})=N(0, \sigma^2Q^{-1}).
\end{align}

Comment: Usually you need to prove the limits, not simply assume them :) Although application of CLT and LLN is routine, it does not hurt to state exactly why it applies, because if you relax the assumptions for disturbances, the CLT need not hold. The assumption of iid and second moment should not be taken for granted.

Comment: Also the main question is why do you need to apply Taylor expansion to the whole gradient, and not simply inside of it, as the OP did. In econometric textbooks more often than not, this is not explained.

Comment: @mpiktas What I did was wrong, because in the NLS setting, usually the gradient will not be linear function, hence our equality will not be a linear one. That's why we apply the taylor expansion to the whole gradient, I think.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. In NLS setting gradient is always non-linear. The reason for Taylor expansion of the whole gradient is related to the application of CLT. My intuition is that it would not be possible to apply CLT (i.e. have a sum of iid variables) if we apply Taylor expansion inside the gradient, i.e. algebraically it would not be possible to cast the resulting expression in the form to which CLT can be applied. This is my guess, though, it would be necessary to demonstrate it explicitly.

Comment: @mpiktas you seem very knowledgeable in econometrics and time-series. What's your recommended bibliography for this subject and time series?

Comment: For econometrics, my favorite author is Wooldridge. For time series the lecture notes by A. van der Vaart are very good, his book on asymptotic statistics is also my favorite. Note that van der Vaart books are very rigorous mathematically, and require quite good mathematical knowledge. For time series I can also recommend J.D. Hamilton, it is more overview than conceptual, but serves very good as a reference.